# CSS are not applied to asp-page tag in razor pages

Tags: css, href, razor-pages, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

It's .NET6 razor pages project and I use VS2022.

This is in _Layout.cshtml.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled ml-2">
    <li>
        <a href="/TEST">TEST</a>
        <a asp-page="TEST/Index">TEST1</a>
    </li>
    ...
```

There are 2 anchor tag in nav bar but css in _Layout.cshtml.css is not applied to one with asp-page tag due to no attribute "b-l76pcumf24"

[image]

Could anyone explain why and how to make it work with asp-page tag helper?

Thanks

Comment: How did you declare the css (eg what did you target?) Sometimes an `a` without an href is treated substantially differently, as well.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: `#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #D68D30;
}`
this is one of the css in _layout.cshtml.css

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I believe asp-page tag helper cares about href..? do I need to add it manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS isolation is a build time feature. Tag helper output is generated at runtime, so they cannot support the CSS isolation feature. This is by design.

Set your own `href` attribute, like in your first link, and don't apply any custom `asp-*` attributes to the anchor.